# How to get dependants of a python package?

Tags: python, pip, pypi

How would I most easily get all direct dependants for a package ?

For example let's take the `flask` package. It depends on `Jinja2` and some other packages.
What other packages use the `Jinja2` package ?

Essentially a pip equivalent of `apt-cache rdepends <package>`

Having the option to see indirect dependants would be nice too.

Comment: Pipenv has `pipenv graph` which shows the top-level dependencies.

Comment: more or less. thanks!

Comment: [_deptree_](https://pypi.org/project/deptree/) `deptree --reverse <package>` -- or [_pipdeptree_](https://pypi.org/project/pipdeptree/) `pipdeptree --reverse --packages <package>`

Comment: I ended up using `pipdeptree -p <package> -r`. thanks all!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at `johnnydep` (https://pypi.org/project/johnnydep/), it will give you a dependency tree with versions for a given package.

Comment: thanks, but I want the reverse of this.